# Best way to mock complex soap responses

Tags: spring, soap, mocking, jax-ws

I have a Java method I want to Unit test, but it requires a mocked SOAP response which contains multiple lists and layers of nodes. I am doing this with a handwritten mock i.e. just manually creating the objects and setting the values, but as the response is quite complex its a pain building up the response. I have a sample XML response is there an easy way of creating the mock using the XML?

Also I looked at Mockito and it looks fine for simple Objects, but it doesnt seem that good for complex responses (I may not be using it to its full potential).

The app stack is Java 1.6, Spring 3 and using JAX-WS.

Comment: Why not decouple your code from the complex model?  Convert it into something simpler, and pass *that* to your code.

Comment: I need the contents of the SOAP message to assert that I have sent the right request. So I am stuck with it.

Comment: I would recommend using XML files, an xml diff tool and JAXB unmarshalling.

Comment: If you're using CXF I've created a JUnit rule which does most of the heavy lifting: https://github.com/skjolber/mockito-soap-cxf

Answer (score 0):

I do something like this

```
@WebService 
public class MyWebService {

        @Autowired
        private ServiceBean serviceBean;

        public SomeReturedData getData(SomeInputData inputData) {
            return serviceBean.getData(inputData);
        } 
}
```

For my UnitTest, I have a mock instanciation of "ServiceBean" which I inject in to @MyWebService, and "MyWebService" is deployed using the "in-vm" transport as described [here](http://jax-ws-commons.java.net/in-vm/)

By Using the in-vm transport, All the XML marshalling/unmarshalling is still done by the web-service framework ,and you only have to deal with Java part.

Now someone might ask, why not test the "ServiceBean" directly, why the need to deply a WS using in-vm transport ? Well 2 things, Using in-vm transport you get to test that the JAXB XML marshalling/unmarshalling is working correctly, and it also allows you to test any intercepting handlers that you might have defined for your webservice.

Comment: This looks good and I am doing something similar.The only thing is my ServiceBean is quite complex and I dont want to have to create the object manually. I was hoping to use a mocking framework or create the mock objects from a sample SOAP requst. Any other ideas?

Comment: You might want to look at SoapUI tool it give you the ability to start a WebService that is mocked out.  This would mean your Junit test is calling into another layer and not being mocked.